# get element id and perform a get request based on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I use this element to fire a modal:

```
<i data-toggle="modal" id="'.$user->user_id.'" data-target="#modal-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#modal-default').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('i').on('click', function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: baseURL + 'users/test/view/' + id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $('#first').val(data.first_name);
      $('#last').val(data.last_name);
      $('#email').val(data.email);
      $('#phone').val(data.phone_number);
    }
  });
});
```

On the first click on the icon, the modal shows, but contains no data. Also, the request to the url is not performed (doesn't appear in Network). The console tells me that id is undefined (on the line that contains the url). 
If I'll click it again without reloading the page, it works.

Is there any way that I can make this work on the first click? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

When the following code is evaluated:

```
$('i').on('click', function(){
  id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

the `id` variable is being declared, but it will be populated only after the user will click the `i` element.

Notice the the `$.ajax` request will be fired immediately after declaring the variable, and not after populating it.

You may want to consider moving the `$.ajax` call inside the `click` callback.